# How to change encoding of the QtTest output?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, encoding, visual-studio-2015

When I execute tests under Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer I get unicode encoded result

```cpp
    void TestProduct::test_case1()
    {       
        QString string = "Кириллица";
        QString result = "кириллица";

        qDebug() << string;
        qDebug() << result;

        QCOMPARE(string, result);
    }
```

Output is

```
PASS    : 'initTestCase()' 
FAIL    : 'test_case1()' Compared values are not the same
   Actual   ((string)): "\u041A\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043B\u043B\u0438\u0446\u0430"
   Expected (result)  : "\u043A\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043B\u043B\u0438\u0446\u0430"
          QDEBUG    : "Кириллица"
          QDEBUG    : "кириллица"
tst_testproduct.cpp(33)
```

Is there any way to get output for actual and expected values in a more readable format like qDebug does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

QT Testlib internally calls `toPrettyUnicode` once it intendes to output QString value.
To fix it I have overrided `toString` function:

```cpp
char *toString(const QString &str)
{
    return qstrdup(str.toUtf8().constData());
}
```